# wheezy maven install

Tags: software-installation, java, reinstall

I have wheezy installed from a pen drive. Updated things and thought I had got `maven` and `eclipse`. But `maven` projects would not compile. I uninstalled all the `maven` programs I could find in  Add/remove software. That was 2 days back. Now can't remember what I removed and anyway fear something was missing. What -all- do I need to install to get `maven` working with java projects—run from command line and eclipse?

Should I reinstall eclipse/STS?

What I tried : downloaded libmaven-install-plugin-java_2.3-4_all.deb'

Tried to install :

```
 dpkg -i libmaven-install-plugin-java_2.3-4_all.deb
```

Output:

> Selecting previously unselected package libmaven-install-plugin-java.
>   (Reading database ... 133826 files and directories currently
>   installed.) Unpacking libmaven-install-plugin-java (from
>   .../libmaven-install-plugin-java_2.3-4_all.deb) ... dpkg: dependency
>   problems prevent configuration of libmaven-install-plugin-java: 
>   libmaven-install-plugin-java depends on libmaven2-core-java; however: 
>   Package libmaven2-core-java is not installed. 
>   libmaven-install-plugin-java depends on libplexus-digest-java;
>   however:   Package libplexus-digest-java is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing libmaven-install-plugin-java (--install): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
>   while processing:  libmaven-install-plugin-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not manually download packages and try to install them with `dpkg`. Instead, use `apt-get` or `aptitude` that will figure out the necessary dependencies and download and install the correct packages for you, for example:

```
aptitude install maven
```

I don't know anything about Maven, so I don't know if this is the correct package and if it's really the one your missing. You will have to figure that out by yourself:

http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=maven

> Now can't remember what I removed

Look into `/var/log/dpkg.log`, `/var/log/aptitude.log` and `/var/log/apt/*`. One of these log files probably contains information on what packages you removed.

Comment: well i re installed and it did not work (installed but still do not have a working maven) Same project works in mac but does not compile in my debian :(

Comment: will start a new thread for the real issue and maybe someone will be able to help. On other similar threads people seem to have solved by reinstall, i removed my ~/.m2 directory and reinstalled, but no cigar

Comment: marked this is as right as it did re install, but again not yet got my java to compile !

Answer (score 1):

```
dpkg -l libmaven-install-plugin-java |egrep ^ii
```